# History of "three quarters" as a period of time

Tags: time, nineteenth-century-english

With the current political crisis in the UK, I was reading about the history of short-lived administrations on Wikipedia, and came across the [Earl of Bath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Pulteney,_1st_Earl_of_Bath#Prime_minister), who tried and failed to set up a government for

> "48 hours, three quarters, seven minutes, and eleven seconds"

This seems a curious way of expressing a length of time (at least to my modern British ear). Assuming "three quarters" means what I would call "three quarters of an hour" (i.e. 45 minutes), then I'd phrase the last bit as "52 minutes and 11 seconds" (maybe even dropping the "and").

The source of that quote appears to be [this 1851 book by Haydn](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Book_of_Dignities/buoKAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%2248%20hours,%20three%20quarters,%20seven%20minutes,%20and%20eleven%20seconds%22&pg=PA93&printsec=frontcover), but I can find no other context for what this length of time was supposed to be.

Assuming my supposition is correct, and "three quarters" meant "45 minutes", was it fashionable at the time to separate off periods of time in this way i.e. to say "three quarters, seven minutes" rather than "52 minutes"? If so, when did common practice change to more like what it is today? Or was this unusual?

Comment: The author of your example appears to be Horace Walpole and is a footnote in the later "The Letters of Horace Walpole, Volume 1
by Horace Walpole".  Walpole himself was active in the mid-18th century: http://www.fullbooks.com/The-Letters-of-Horace-Walpole-Volume15.html

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems to me that calling an hour and a half '90 minutes' is comparatively modern (20th century?).

Comment: Three quarters of an hour is idiomatic. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+quarters+of+an+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthree%20quarters%20of%20an%20hour%3B%2Cc0